# Solution to a Partial Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

May I know how to solve the following partial differential equation?

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=A\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}+B\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}+Cz+D$,

where $z=z(x,y)$ is a function of $x$ and $y$; $A, B, C, D$ are constants.

If boundary conditions are needed, here they are:

$z(x,\pm\infty)=0,x\geq 0$.

Many thanks!!

Comment: Did you try anything? What are your own ideas? What's your motivation to solve this equation?

Comment: I read somewhere about the solution to $\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=A\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}+B\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}+Cz$ (without computational details) and am curious how the solution is obtained and what if there is a constant added to the equation. I am not an expert on this field and I have no idea how to approach this kind of questions.

Comment: Say that the solution to $\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=A\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}+B\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}+Cz$ is $z=f(x,y)$; then there any way to express the solution to $\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=A\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}+B\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}+Cz+D$ as some expression of $f(x,y)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trial solution of the homogenous equation $\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=A\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}+B\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}+Cz$ has the form $z_h=Ee^{ax+by}$ and hence
$$aEe^{ax+by}=AbEe^{ax+by}+Bb^2Ee^{ax+by}+CEe^{ax+by}
\\ \{Ab+Bb^2+C-a\}Ee^{ax+by}=0
\\ Ab+Bb^2+C-a=0\implies b=f(a),b=g(a)\\ 
$$
For example if $b=2a,3a$, then $$z_h=E_1e^{ax+2ay}+E_2e^{ax+3ay}=F(x+2y)+G(x+3y)$$
The particular solution of the non-homogenous equation $\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=A\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}+B\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}+Cz+D$ has the general form of the term "$D$" i.e.  $z_p=F$ is a constant and so
$$0=0+0+CF+D \implies F=\frac{-D}{C}$$
The general solution is $$z=z_h+z_p$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am curious how the solution to the non-homogeneous case is linked to the solution to the homogeneous case: say that the solution to $\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=A\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}+B\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}+Cz$ is $z=f(x,y)$; then there any way to express the solution to $\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=A\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}+B\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}+Cz+D$ as some expression of $f(x,y)$?

Comment: The general solution is the sum of the solution of the homogenous equation and a particular solution of the non-homogenous equation. Note that both solutions should be independent i.e one can't express linearly one of them in terms of the other

Comment: Then how can I find one particular solution? Sorry that I am not familiar with PDE and not sure what $z_h$, $z_p$ and $z_c$ mean in your answer.

Comment: I added some new

Comment: It is now very clear! Thank you sooo much!!

Comment: This is simply wrong.

Comment: @Artem why is it wrong?

Comment: @Semsem I am really not sure how to answer your question. Try to look up "the heat equation" for example to see how this kind of problems can be solved. Also note the boundary conditions $z(x,\pm\infty)$ which do not hold for those very particular solutions that you found using your anzats.

Comment: @Artem for example consider the equation $u_{xx}-u_{yy}+2u_x-2u_y=0\implies a^2-b^2+2a-2b=0$ and so $a=b,a=-b-2$ and the solution is $u(x,y)=F(x+y)+e^{-2x}G(-x+y)$. This method works well if we could find a linear relationship between $a$ and $b$ otherwise it fails. What is "anzats"?

Comment: @Semsem It is a different equation, of hyperbolic type. The original equation is of parabolic type. I advise you to read my previous comment and follow the directions.

Comment: @Zuriel this answer is incorrect and Artem is right since in your equation you can't solve linearly for $b$ in terms of $a$, i am so sorry, this method work if $a$ and $b$ are linearly related which is not your case as i finally noticed. again i'm so sorry.

Comment: @Artem you are right this method fails in this case. sorry for inactivity